# BeautifulSoup unable to find parsed element

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Anyone able to help me get the href from the following page: https://www.polarcapitaltechnologytrust.co.uk/Key-Information/#/Fund-Manager-Commentary

Looking to get the following href from below HTML:

```
<a href="/srp/lit/NyaGGV/Fact-Sheet_Polar-Capital-Technology-Trust-plc-Polar-Capital-Technology-Trust-plc-Ordinary-Shares_30-06-2021.pdf" target="_blank" class="document-link" sa-document-b64="eyJsaXRlcmF0dXJlX3R5cGUiOiAiVHJ1c3RzIHwgRmFjdCBTaGVldCIsICJkb2N1bWVudF9sYW5ndWFnZSI6ICJlbl9HQiIsICJ1bWJyZWxsYSI6ICJQb2xhciBDYXBpdGFsIFRlY2hub2xvZ3kgVHJ1c3QgcGxjIiwgImZ1bmQiOiAiVGVjaG5vbG9neSIsICJmdW5kX2dyb3VwIjogbnVsbCwgImZ1bmRfdHlwZSI6ICJJbnZlc3RtZW50IFRydXN0IiwgInNoYXJlX2NsYXNzIjogIlBvbGFyIENhcGl0YWwgVGVjaG5vbG9neSBUcnVzdCBwbGMgLSBPcmRpbmFyeSBTaGFyZXMiLCAic2hhcmVfY2xhc3NlcyI6IFsiUG9sYXIgQ2FwaXRhbCBUZWNobm9sb2d5IFRydXN0IHBsYyAtIE9yZGluYXJ5IFNoYXJlcyJdLCAiZG9jdW1lbnRfZGF0ZSI6ICIyMDIxLTA2LTMwIn0="><svg class="document-icon" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 21 27" style="enable-background:new 0 0 21 27;" xml:space="preserve" width="21" height="27"><g><path fill="#005187" d="M11,2l0,6l0,2h2h6v15H2V2H11 M13,0L13,0L13,0L13,0z M13,0H0v27h21V8h-8L13,0L13,0z"></path></g><rect x="4" y="19" width="13" height="2" fill="#005187"></rect><rect class="trust-color-rect" x="4" y="15" width="13" height="2" fill="#004070"></rect><path d="M11,1h2c0,0,2,1,4,3s3,4,3,4v2" fill="none" stroke="#005187" stroke-width="2" stroke-miterlimit="10"></path></svg><div class="document-details"><span class="document-name">June</span><div class="document-date">30.06.2021</div></div></a>
```

Currently trying using BS in the following code:

```
with requests.Session() as req:
    data = {
        "agree": "",
        "disclaimer": ""
    }
    req.post('https://www.worldwidewh.com/disclaimer', data=data)
    r = req.get('https://www.polarcapitaltechnologytrust.co.uk/Key-Information/#/Fund-Manager-Commentary')
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'lxml')
    link_finder = soup.findAll('a', href=re.compile('Fact-Sheet_Polar-Capital-Technology'))
    url_PCT_factsheet = link_finder[0].get('href')

url_PCT_factsheet
```

However, nothing seems to work for me, as I am unable to find the given element in the HTML code when parsing.

Comment: It appears to be generated in some way dynamically, as I don't see it in the html using requests. I also don't see it fetched through XHR. You may need to use selenium here to first allow the page to render, then use your code to parse it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need to adjust a parameter in the headers. This worked for me:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import re

headers = {'Cookie': 'srpperm="UT=P&JR=UK&timestamp=2021-08-16T13%3A59%3A46.613829%2B00%3A00"'}
r = requests.get('https://www.polarcapitaltechnologytrust.co.uk/Key-Information/', headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
link_finder = soup.find_all('a', href=re.compile('Fact-Sheet_Polar-Capital'))
url_PCT_factsheet = link_finder[0].get('href')

print(len(link_finder))

for i in link_finder:
    print(i['href'])
```

Comment: Thank you! Worked perfectly. May I ask, how you found the cookie stamp? 'Cookie': 'srpperm="UT=P&JR=UK&timestamp=2021-08-16T13%3A59%3A46.613829%2B00%3A00"'}

Answer (score 1):

To get first href use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')

rawSoup = soup.find('div', {'class': 'document-list-item'})

for a in rawSoup.find_all('a', href=True):
    if a.text:
        print(a['href'])
```

To get all of the hrefs use:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(r, 'html.parser')
        
rawSoup = soup.find_all('div', {'class': 'document-list-item'})

for item in rawSoup:
    for a in item.find_all('a', href=True):
        if a.text:
            print(a['href'])
```